# The requested resource is not available. Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have 5 hello world projects that have the same error:

"description: The requested resource is not available."

I'm using jdk7, tomcat7, maven3.1.1. I always use mvn clean/package.

Here is one of this projects

/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<!-- the package is right( checked it twice) -->
<context:component-scan base-package="ua.abond.tutor.controller" />

<!-- without this tag I get "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SecondSite/hello.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'" -->
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<!-- also tried mvc:annotation-driven  and context:annotation-config tags 
    didnt help too-->

<bean id="viewResolver"
                        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
                        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/" p:suffix=".jsp">
</bean>
        <!-- prefix is right, if I had permission, I would have shared my root screenshot -->
</beans>
```

/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>SecondSite</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
            <!-- also tried /*, *, /dispatcher/*, /dispatcher/*.htm and /  -->
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

controller

```
@Controller
public class Home {
    String message = "Welcome to your 1st Maven Spring project !";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")//also tried: hello, /hello.htm ... no result
    public ModelAndView showMessage() {
        System.out.println("from controller");
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

and my pages

1)index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tutorial | Spring</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h4>
        <a href="hello.htm">Click Here</a>
    </h4>
</body>
</html>
```

2)WEB-INF/pages/hello.jsp    ------  The page I cant reach

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tutorial | Spring</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h4>${message}</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

console

```
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: D:\Programmes\JRE7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.4;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL ;;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\ ;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\;.
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:15 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SecondSite' did not find a matching property.
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 475 ms
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:16 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:16 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jan 28 20:57:16 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:16 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:17 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0'
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:17 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 692 ms
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:17 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:17 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Jan 28 20:57:17 EET 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:17 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:17 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0'
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:17 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 178 ms
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 28, 2014 8:57:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2025 ms
```

Comment: Post dir structure of your app.

Comment: whatch here:
http://imgur.com/IcaIpQm

Comment: is that error a browser error, or in your server logs?  If it's a browser error, also give us the URL you're testing with

Comment: http://imgur.com/E2CQWv9
browser screenshot

Comment: maybe this answer of mine to another question can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30468725/1201725

Answer (score 0):

The dispatcher servlet is only configured to handle *.htm files, so when accessing /hello it won't work.

Try this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Clean the project and try run again

Comment: Still no result...Hands down, I really cant understand why it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in spring configuration.